# WAS cannot test datasource connection until changes are synchronized

Tags: jdbc, websphere

When I create a JDBC data source connection from WAS admin console and do 'test connection', I get error saying I need to first synchronize the changes with all other nodes before  I can test the connection/ What is the reason for this kind of restriction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kaushik,

The test is executed on the node agent or Server (based on the scope that you specify)

When you create the configuration they are stored in the Deployment manager. The node agents and servers are not aware of this unless a synchronization is performed. Notice that the deployment manager keeps a master copy and dishes out the relevent files to the various node via the synchronization activity.

This is the reason why the admin console tells you that it needs to be synchronized.

HTH

Manglu